# Ghost Flags in Chat

Tags: bug, chat, chat-flags

Whenever a chat room is entered or reloaded, a flag is present next to my avatar. When clicked, the "There are no flags to display." message comes up and the flag vanishes.

This has been confirmed by [other users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34833195#34833195) and has been going on for a couple of days before I noticed this behavior.

Comment: I was [having this too](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34832234#34832234)